how to import ConversableAgent from autogen
I am using Python 3.12 and have installed autogen package. When I try following import:
from autogen import ConversableAgent

I get error msg, as follows:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConversableAgent' from 'autogen' 
(C:\Users\hp\GenAI\.venv\Lib\site-packages\autogen\__init__.py)


Resolved. the module tobe installed is 'pyautogen'.
